# views expose filter by taxonomy

Tags: views

I have this structure :

- mobile

  - Lg

    - V10
    - V20
  - Samsung

    - A7
    - J5
  - Nokia

    - 1100
    - 1110
- laptop ...
- tablet ...

How can I create that with view expose filter? (step by step filter)

Comment: You get the Taxonomy structure out of the box in an Exposed Filter if you choose the Dropdown option. What exactly do you want to do that is different from what is available? What do you mean "step by step"?

Comment: step by step : when i select mobile .. views show all mobile.
when i select mobilr -> lg ... views show all lg phone ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the special type of filter `Has taxonomy terms (with depth)`.

1. Add a new Filter **Has taxonomy terms (with depth)**
2. Select your Vocabulary in the new filter settings,
   Selection type: **Dropdown**
   **Show hierarchy in dropdown**
   Depth **2** (this will include 2 levels of children of a chosen term)
3. **Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it** and **Apply**

You will get a drop-down that shows your terms with hierarchy.

If you don't want a dropdown you can use a module like [Better exposed filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) to use radio buttons instead.

Comment: At first we must add "Content : Taxonomoy term on node" as relationship ?

Comment: Do your nodes already have the Taxonomy field on them? They probably do (Entity reference field). Then you don't need Relationships, Taxonomy information is already available in that View. If you can add a Field showing Taxonomy terms on your nodes, you can also add a Filter for those terms, without any Relationships. 
Relationships are used to include extra related information from other database tables, but Taxonomy should already be available. If it isn't you have to share more about your node-taxonomy structure.

Comment: yes. it have taxonomy field

Comment: No, you don't need any Relationships in this case ;).